# LINQ en entorno de producción

Tags: c#, linq, orm

estoy realizando un proyecto con Linq en c#, con este ningún problema, ya que hay mucha información al respecto en internet, pero toda la documentación y tutoriales que he encontrado, se basan siempre en una estructura de datos en local, es decir con una base de datos existente en el PC de desarrollo, ¿pero como debo hacerlo para configurar mi aplicación para otra máquina?
Sin un ORM intermedio, bastaba con cambiar la cadena de conexión y ya estaba, pero para hacerlo con linq o con entity framework no sé cómo debo hacerlo, me pueden ayudar por favor?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Qué versión de EF estás utilizando?

Comment: Si ya mapeaste la base de datos con EF, solo basta con cambiar la direccion de la base de datos en el App.Config o web.config depende de donde te guarda la conexion.

Comment: La Versión es la última estable (6.4.4)

Comment: No hay ninguna diferencia.. Si usas o no Linq da lo mismo al momento de pasarlo a producción. Como indicas debes cambiar el connectionString y asegurarte que tu server IIS soporte la versión de framework en la que construiste el aplicativo.